# Query On node timing out (mysql2)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

maybe you could help me.

i have a node application using express which is making a query into a mysql database.
i'm using mysql2 to connect to it.

This is a query with some parameters ( two dates) and although it runs in 0 seconds on the database , in node it times out.

Here's the code for the query:

```
controleTemp.prototype.getFreeVeichles = function(dataInicio,dataFim,callback){
    var queryTxt=

    'select distinct ID,Modelo,Fabricante,'+
    'Placa,Ano,Motor,control.Status,Disponivel,Quilometragem,Atribuido from '+
    'controletemp as control '+
    'JOIN booking as book '+
    'ON control.id = book.veiculoID '+
    'Where veiculoID not in( '+
    'select veiculoid from ' +
    'controletemp as ct '+
    'JOIN booking as bk '+
    'ON ct.id = bk.veiculoID '+
    'Where \''+dataInicio+'\' between '+
    'dataInicio and dataFim OR \''+dataFim+'\' between '+
    'dataInicio and dataFim)';


    this._dbConnection.query(queryTxt);
```

thank you all in advance

Comment: Any other simple query executes fine? Are you sure that connection is fine?

Comment: please show the output of `console.log(queryTxt)` before hitting dbConnection?

Comment: Since that is most probably column name you should use backticks here `'Where \`'+dataInicio+'\` between '+`. But on other hand, I think you missplaced values and column names. so it should be inverse like `'Where dataInicio between \''+ dataInicio +'\' and \''  + dataFim +' ...`

Comment: Thank you for you reply, i've found out that i was missing the callback so that the function could return.

Answer (score 0):

You miss-placed column name and values you pass to filter.
And here is a bit optimized query that should do you logic I believe:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT ' +
'    ID,Modelo,Fabricante,' +
'    Placa,Ano,Motor,control.Status,Disponivel,Quilometragem,Atribuido ' +
'FROM controletemp as control ' +
'JOIN booking as book ' +
'    ON control.id = book.veiculoID ' +
'WHERE (dataInicio < \'' + dataInicio +'\' OR dataInicio >  \'' + dataFim +'\')' +
' AND (dataFim <  \'' + dataInicio +'\' OR dataFim > \'' + dataFim +'\');'
```